# GitLab API access failing after upgrade

Tags: gitlab

I have recently updated GitLab to version 7.14, and when I run

```
 sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following error

```
Check GitLab API access: FAILED: Failed to connect to internal API
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
```

I have gitlab running behind a reverse proxy with the following rules set up

```
DNAT            net             loc:192.168.122.38:22    tcp     2227    -               <externalip>
DNAT            net             loc:192.168.122.38:80    tcp     2280    -               <externalip>
DNAT            net             loc:192.168.122.38:443   tcp     2443    -               <externalip>
```

and gitlab-shell/config.yml looks like

```
 GitLab user. git by default
 user: git

# Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls
gitlab_url: "https://<external_url>:2443/"

# Repositories path
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories"

# File used as authorized_keys for gitlab user
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"

ssh_port: 2227

self_signed_cert: true
```

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configuration you have described the issue is that `gitlab-shell` is trying to access GitLab at https://:2443. However, you point out that only ports 22, 80 and 443 are proxied. You need to adjust your `gitlab-shell` configuration so it either points at localhost at an appropriate port or at port 443 on the external URL.